# How to remove the null or empty values in map of the React table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How to check if my *{row.storeId}* is null or empty and if that's the case, I wanted to  place **NA** in `<TableCell>`.

```
{props.tableData.map(row => (
          <TableRow key={row.storeId}>
            <TableCell>{row.name}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{row.storeId}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{concatenateAddress(row.address)}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{capabilitiesColumn(row.capabilities)}</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        ))}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simple check whether it's null or not as follows:
[Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

```js
<TableCell>{row.storeId ?? 'NA'}</TableCell>
```

You cannot use logical `or` and `ternary` opreator if `storeId` is `0` i.e. [`Falsy Value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) then it will print `Na`

```js
<TableCell>{row.storeId || 'NA'}</TableCell>
<TableCell>{row.storeId ? row.storeId : 'NA'}</TableCell>
```

```js
const a=0
const b=1
const c=null
console.log("Logical OR (||)")
console.log(a||"Na")
console.log(b||"Na")
console.log(c||"Na")


console.log("Nullish coalescing operator (??)")
console.log(a??"Na")
console.log(b??"Na")
console.log(c??"Na")


console.log("Ternary Operator")
console.log(a?a:"Na")
console.log(b?b:"Na")
console.log(c?c:"Na")
```

Answer (score 3):

Just check for it?

```
<TableCell>{row.storeId ? row.storeId : 'NA'}</TableCell>
```

Learn more about ternary operators [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), though this could also be done without one:

```
{props.tableData.map(row => {
  let storeId = row.storeId;
  if (!storeId( {
    storeId = 'NA';
  }

  return (
    <TableRow key={row.storeId}>
      <TableCell>{row.name}</TableCell>
      <TableCell>{storeId}</TableCell>
      <TableCell>{concatenateAddress(row.address)}</TableCell>
      <TableCell>{capabilitiesColumn(row.capabilities)}</TableCell>
    </TableRow>
  );
})}
```

Comment: Ternary operator will fail if `storeId` is 0 or `Falsy` value

Comment: Yes, certainly something to look out for if your ids are numbers

Comment: @MatthewHerbst yes and therefor it's adviced to use `Nullish coalescing operator (??)` which checks for `null` and `undefined`.

Comment: @GodWin depends on what you are trying to support. For example, older browsers will not support `??` so you will have to transform the code through a tool such as babel, while a ternary will "just work". Always tradeoffs when writing client-side code

Answer (score 1):

you can simply do this
but take into your consideration that you will face an issue with the key of the row

```
{props.tableData.map(row => (
          <TableRow key={row.storeId}>
            <TableCell>{row.name}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{row.storeId || 'NA'}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{concatenateAddress(row.address)}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{capabilitiesColumn(row.capabilities)}</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        ))}
```